# Not able to mount Docker Volume for PhpMyAdmin

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, docker-volume

I've install MySQL and PhpMyAdmin on docker

MySQL volume mount works perfectly fine,
But I also want container's `/var/www/html/libraries`, `/var/www/html/themes` folders to be saved/persisted to my host.
So that If I change any file and it stays like that..

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root


  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./phpmyadmin/libraries:/var/www/html/libraries # Here's the problem
      - ./phpmyadmin/themes:/var/www/html/themes # Here's the problem
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
```

The current problem is,
it does create the folders `/phpmyadmin/libraries`, `/phpmyadmin/themes`
But inside they're empty and the container's directories (`/var/www/html/libraries`, `/var/www/html/themes`) also becomes empty.

I'm very new to Docker, and currently I've no clue :(

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, Docker volumes only map host directories to containers and not the other way around. What's the use case for persisting these files on your local machine?

Comment: Ok I understand but, If you look at my `docker-compose.yml`, I'm doing the same thing for MySql service, `./var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`, in this case first I dont have the var/lib/mysql folder on my host, but on first start docker creates this folder on my host, and get all the files from the container, and after that if i change anything on host the changes also gets made in the container. I want to achieve the same for PHPMyAdmin

Comment: In that case, I think the MySQL image comes built with an empty `/var/lib/mysql` and then populates it at run time after the volumes have been mounted. You can achieve something similar if you extend the `Dockerfile` for PHPMyAdmin. I'll write up a more detailed guide as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `/var/www/html` is populated at build time and volumes are mounted at run time which causes `/var/www/html` to be overwritten by what you have locally (i.e. nothing).

You need to extend the Dockerfile for PHPMyAdmin to delay populating those directories until after the volumes have been mounted. You'll need something like this setup:

Modify `docker-compose.yml` to the following:

```
...
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    build:
      # Use the Dockerfile located at ./build/phpmyadmin/Dockerfile to build this image
      context: ./build/phpmyadmin
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./phpmyadmin/libraries:/var/www/html/libraries
      - ./phpmyadmin/themes:/var/www/html/themes
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
```

Create a file at `./build/phpmyadmin/Dockerfile` with this content:

```
FROM phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest

# Move the directories you want into a temporary directory
RUN mv /var/www/html /tmp/

# Modify the start up of this image to use a custom script
COPY ./custom-entrypoint.sh /custom-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /custom-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/custom-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Create a custom entrypoint at `./build/phpmyadmin/custom-entrypoint.sh` with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copy over the saved files
cp -r /tmp/html /var/www

# Kick off the original entrypoint
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Then you can build and start everything with `docker-compose up --build`.

Note: this will probably cause issues for you if you're trying to version control these directories - you'll probably need to modify `custom-entrypoint.sh`.

Comment: Have you tested this. It doesn't seem to be working